# How to mount data directory?

Tags: docker, percona

I am not able to start percona mysql dockerized instance if I try to mount the data directory like this:

```
docker run --name percona57f -p 3384:3306 -v /my/custom3384:/etc/mysql/conf.d -v /storage/data3384:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=india3384 -e INIT_TOKUDB=1 -d percona/percona-server:5.7
```

The error is as shown below:

```
[ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory exists and is not writable. Aborting.
[ERROR] Aborting
```

The command will work if I do not include the data directory like this...

```
docker run --name percona57g -p 3384:3306 -v /my/custom3384:/etc/mysql/conf.d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=india3384 -e INIT_TOKUDB=1 -d percona/percona-server:5.7
```

But it is very important for me to mount the data directory on host machine. Any way to enable this -v /storage/data3384:/var/lib/mysql

Comment: What are the permissions on the directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command before **docker run**:

```
chown 1001 /my/custom3384
```

This is the UID for the **mysql** user, as shown in the Dockerfile for the **percona** image:

https://github.com/percona/percona-docker/blob/master/percona-server/Dockerfile

```
RUN useradd -u 1001 -r -g 0 -s /sbin/nologin \
            -c "Default Application User" mysql
```